# Runge Kutta Method for a Lindblad Equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, computational-physics, quantum-optics

I am solving a [Lindblad equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindblad_equation) for a dissipative Harmonic Oscillator.
My Hamiltonian is time dependent,

My Lindblad Equation can be written as
\begin{equation}
\frac{d\rho}{dt}=\frac{[H(t),\rho]}{i\hbar}+D(\rho,a)
\end{equation}
where the last part $D(\rho,a)$ represents the Linbald operator due to the dissipation.

Considering Hamiltonian is constant over the interval $t_{1}$ to $t_{1}+dt$.
I used the Runge-Kutta fourth order (RK4) method in each time interval and integrated the above equation.
I would like to know whether my procedure could be justified?
I have seen methods which refer to the interaction picture then apply the RK4 method. I think the method that I mentioned is even more simple, but I would like to know its validity. My mathematical justification is the following
\begin{eqnarray}
U(t)=\exp{\left(-\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_{0}^{t}H(\tau)d\tau\right)}\\
U(t,t+dt)=\exp{\left(-\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_{t}^{t+dt}H(\tau)d\tau\right)}\\
\end{eqnarray}
Now I suppose, in the given tiny interval my Hamiltonian is constant, hence I can move it outside the integral and I get,
\begin{eqnarray}
U(t,t+dt)=\exp{\left(-\frac{i}{\hbar}H(t)\int_{t}^{t+dt}d\tau\right)}\\
U(t,t+dt)=\exp{\left(-\frac{i}{\hbar}H(t)dt\right)}\\
\end{eqnarray}
Now I can use the Taylor expansion and use the Runge-Kutta to integrate the function. 
But every time the $U(t,t+dt)$ operator changes. Is my method legitimate?

Comment: Your method will violate unitarity in the limit of $D \rightarrow 0$, so if you are worried about that you may want to come up with a unitary integrator with a $D$ kick in the middle. At least, it looks like it might. Runge-Kutta is not intrinsically unitary, although there are unitary Runge-Kutta type algorithms.

Comment: Method's wrong. Violates unitarity. Try using the Fritzpack's modified Runge Kutta method.

Comment: Hi @JAMES Could you please provide me a link to the Fritzpack's method. I googled it but I didn't find anything related to that.

Comment: Do you get the correct method now? The method you described is not RK4, and it should be of order one only because you haven't evaluated at the middle point U(t,t+dt/2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi guys I found the answer. The answer is Magnus expansion method. My method is not a good approximation. The method that I described is valid only in a very very small interval of time. Hence the numerical algorithm will be slow and inaccurate. There is a truncation error due to the  Zassenhaus formula 
$$e^{-i/\hbar(t_{1}+t_{2})(H(t_{1})+H(t_{2})}= e^{-i/\hbar\,(t_{1}+t_{2})H(t_{1})}  e^{-i/\hbar\,(t_{1}+t_{2})H(t_{2})} e^{1/\hbar^2\frac{(t_{1}+t_{2})^2}{2} [H(t_{1}),H(t_{2})]} \cdots$$. 
The last additional error factor comes since we deal with time dependent hamiltonian and the Hamiltonian of different time  doesn't commute each other. Hence we have to use the [Magnus expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnus_expansion), which is aimed to find an equivalent matrix as a  linear combinations of Hamiltonians at different time and the linear coefficients are cleverly chosen to eliminate the error due to Zassenhaus formula. I found [this article](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0370157308004092) very useful.

Answer (score 0):

That appears to be a very bad thing to do. The LHS measures how a quantity changes with time. The only time-dependent quantity on the RHS is the Hamiltonian. You hold it time-independent, for your small interval, and integrate $d\rho/dt = f(\rho)$. For the next interval, you again arrest the time-dependence. So, in totality, between these two steps, your Hamiltonian hasn't advanced in time at all, whereas a truly time-dependent Hamiltonian should have!

Comment: What if I evaluate H(t) using time dependent Runge-Kutta and evaluate H(t) at H(t+dt/2) and H(t+dt) in these instants ?

Answer (score -1):

Yeah! That's right. The method's fine for a time independent Hamiltonian, but not for an $H(t)$.